# How to change theorem numbering when macro file is involved

Tags: macros, amsthm

In my macro file, I have certain theorem environments defined, for example.

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
```

Again, these lines are in my `macros.sty` file of shortcuts.

In the past, I have changed the numbering of theorem, etc... by using `\numberwithin`. I have recently learned that I can instead edit the `\newtheorem` line. For example, if I want results numbered according to section I can use

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

My question now is about future situations when I have two documents, which both use the same `macros.sty` file, but in one document I want to number results by `section` and in the other document I want to number results by something else, say `chapter`.

How can I accomplish this without creating two different `.sty` files?

EDIT: I think I should add that I am looking for a way to do this without going back to `\numberwithin`. The reason for this is because `\numberwithin` doesn't seem to work well with the `thmtools` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use options to the package, say, `drivercounter`, which is set to default as `section` in the package (mymacro.sty) and to `chapter` in the file `demochapter.tex`.

*For simplification I did not add the other theorem definitions*

There could be of course other package options, but this is the choice of the OP...

### mymacro.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mymacro}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

%% Declare a package option 
\DeclareOptionX{drivercounter}{%
  \def\TheoremDriverCounter{#1}%
}

%% Preset the option with 'section' value
\ExecuteOptionsX{drivercounter=section}

%% Process the options given to the package 
\ProcessOptionsX


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\TheoremDriverCounter]


\endinput
```

### demosection.sty

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mymacro}


\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{theorem}
Blabla
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Blabla
\end{theorem}

\section{Second}

\begin{theorem}
Blabla
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

### demochapter.tex

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[drivercounter=chapter]{mymacro}


\begin{document}


\chapter{First}

\section{First}

\begin{theorem}
Blabla
\end{theorem}

\chapter{Second}

\section{First of 2nd}

\begin{theorem}
Blabla 1
\end{theorem}


\section{Second of 2nd}

\begin{theorem}
Blabla 2
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

**Snapshot for demochapter.tex**

[image]