# How to \DeclareOption with a variable?

Tags: macros, package-options, options

I know `\DeclareOption{option name}{option content}` but how is this used to pass a variable number into the package? for example, `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` passes `1in` to the `margin` option of geometry; how could I replicate that behavior in my own package?

Comment: A good resource for this (in LaTeX2e at least) is the [`xkeyval` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval).

Comment: See for example my answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224405/how-to-change-theorem-numbering-when-macro-file-is-involved

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean by "a variable number"?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.